# How to solve "Expression has changed after it was checked." when occuring because of the @Input variable update?

Tags: angular, eventemitter, event-binding

When the webpage container is scrolled I use eventemitters which send to the parent element the target. The parent page sends to another child - the menu- the targets so that the menu can activate / deactivate correspondingly the menu titles. The variables are sent and updated ok from the container to the parent but when sent further from parent to child (menu component) the error

```
ERROR Error: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'Home: undefined'. Current value: 'Home: true'."
```

Update parent:

```
<scroll-card (id_active) ="activate_id($event)"></scroll-card>
```

and the component

```
export class Parent implements OnInit {
    home:boolean;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    activate_id(message: string){
        if(message == "Home"){
            this.home=true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I send the data to the child:

```
<menu [Home] ="home"></menu>
```

And this is how I receive the data:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'menu',
    templateUrl: 'menu',
    styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']

    export class Menu implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    @Input() Home;
}
```

Comment: show where it is changing. parent component

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue and share the forked link here? https://angular-e3k6qu.stackblitz.io

Comment: Helo Adrita
The link does not work for me unfortunately..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to really understand why this happens, you need to show how you emit a change to `id_active`. However, it is always possible to manually trigger change detection:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class Parent implements OnInit {
    home:boolean;

    constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    activate_id(message: string){
        if(message == "Home"){
            this.home=true;
            this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        }
    }
}
```